# System.AccessViolationException On Web Forms ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, oledb

*This is a school project

I'v been using this project on couple of computers, in the **first computer my project run perfectly**, but on other computer it's giving me a `System.AccessViolationException` on 'random' places on code.

I'm using web service, asmx page and aspx pages, my database is Microsoft Access.

I'm trying to belive the bug is a problem with my second computer settings and not on my code, because the code run perfect on others computer.

This is one place that giving me a bug:

javascript:

```
    function sendList(r, id, subject, content) {
        $('#modal1').modal('close');
            $.getJSON("/API/UIService.asmx/SendMessage?currentUserID=" + id + "&reciverID=" + r + "&subject=" + subject + "&content=" + content, function (msg) {
                msg = fixMsg(msg);
                if (msg == "Message sent") {
                    modalAlert(fixMsg(msg));
                    inbox.update();
                    sent.update();
                }
                else
                    alert(msg);
            });
    }
```

Web service method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SendMessage(int currentUserId, string reciverID, string subject, string content)
{
    try
    {
        string[] res = reciverID.Split(',');
        List<Message> m = new List<Message>();
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
        {

            Message msg = new Message()
            {
                SenderID = currentUserId,
                ReciverID = int.Parse(res[i]),
                Subject = subject.Replace("'", ""),
                Content = content.Replace("'", ""),
                IsRead = false,
                SendDate = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(),
                DeletedBy = -1
            };
            m.Add(msg);
        }
        MessageService.SendList(m);
        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(jsonSerialiser.Serialize("Message sent"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(jsonSerialiser.Serialize("Server Error: " + ex.Message));
    }
}
```

MessageService.SendList method:

```
public static void SendList(List<Message> msgs)
{
    DataTable messages = new DataTable();
    messages.Columns.Add("MessageSenderID");
    messages.Columns.Add("MessageReciverID");
    messages.Columns.Add("MessageSubject");
    messages.Columns.Add("MessageContent");
    messages.Columns.Add("MessageIsRead");
    messages.Columns.Add("MessageSendDate");
    messages.Columns.Add("MessageDeletedBy");

    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Count; i++)
    {
            DataRow dr = messages.NewRow();
            dr["MessageSenderID"] = msgs[i].SenderID;
            dr["MessageReciverID"] = msgs[i].ReciverID;
            dr["MessageSubject"] = msgs[i].Subject;
            dr["MessageContent"] = msgs[i].Content;
            dr["MessageIsRead"] = false;
            dr["MessageSendDate"] = DateTime.Now;
            dr["MessageDeletedBy"] = -1;
            messages.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Connect.GetConnectionString());

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Messages(MessageSenderID, MessageReciverID, MessageSubject, MessageContent, " +
        "MessageIsRead, MessageSendDate, MessageDeletedBy) " +
            "VALUES " +
        "(@MessageSenderID, @MessageReciverID, @MessageSubject, @MessageContent, @MessageIsRead, " +
        "@MessageSendDate, @MessageDeletedBy)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageSenderID", OleDbType.Integer);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageReciverID", OleDbType.Integer);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageSubject", OleDbType.WChar, 255);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageContent", OleDbType.WChar, 255);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageIsRead", OleDbType.Boolean, 2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageSendDate", OleDbType.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MessageDeletedBy", OleDbType.Integer);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Prepare();

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = int.Parse(messages.Rows[i]["MessageSenderID"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters[1].Value = int.Parse(messages.Rows[i]["MessageReciverID"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters[2].Value = messages.Rows[i]["MessageSubject"].ToString();
        cmd.Parameters[3].Value = messages.Rows[i]["MessageContent"].ToString();
        cmd.Parameters[4].Value = bool.Parse(messages.Rows[i]["MessageIsRead"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters[5].Value = DateTime.Parse(messages.Rows[i]["MessageSendDate"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters[6].Value = int.Parse(messages.Rows[i]["MessageDeletedBy"].ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    OleDbTransaction trance = con.BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Transaction = trance;
    trance.Commit();
    con.Close();
}
```

The code stuck at **`con.Open();`** and giving: `System.AccessViolationException Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted`

Comment: Did any of these help? https://www.google.com.au/search?q=connection.open+access+AccessViolationException

Comment: Where is stored Access file? Can you try to set its folder full permission?

Comment: all the project run on local host iis express